# Angular JS freezing DOM when using ng-repeat to iterate through massive dataset

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I currently have an app that when a button is clicked, it will send an $http request and return some information. I then update `$scope` variables `rows` and `columns` with said data. `ng-repeat` proceeds to loop through all my data.

When I increase the data past 1000 objects it completely locks up the DOM. How can I optimize my code so that it doesn't lock up the DOM **ever**? This is important as my users need to be able to do things on the page while the data is being iterated through. I need the hypothetical solution to work with up to 10000 rows.

***My HTML...***

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="column in columns | orderBy:columnToSortBy:reverse">
            <h6 ng-bind="column.name" ng-click='sortBy(column.name)'></h6>
            <img src='/static/images/asc.gif' ng-show="orderByAsc">
            <img src='/static/images/desc.gif' ng-show="orderByDesc">
            <img src='/static/images/bg.gif' ng-show="orderByNothing">
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in row" ng-bind="value"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

***Here is the controller where the HTML to be appended is being created, appended, and `$compile`'ed...***

```
mainQueryModule.controller("newQueryController", function($scope, $http, $compile){
 var results = {columns:[{"type": "STRING", "name": "nk"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Bn"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Sk"},{"type": "STRING", "name": "ank"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Bnk"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Skk"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Name"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Phone"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Age"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Tank"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Bank"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Skunk"}], rows:[]};
 for(index = 0; index < 1000; index++){
      results['rows'].push({nk: "select * from faker 100000000000", Bn: 35, Sk: 567, ank: "ank", Bnk: "Bnk", Skk: "Skk", Name: "Erik", Phone: 100000+index, Age: 29+index, Bank: "Big"+index, Tank: 16+index, Skunk: "123"+index})
 } 

 $scope.runQuery = (client_id) => {
      // $http.post("fakeurl/", {test:123}).then(function(response){
      //      console.log(response)
           $scope.columns = results["columns"];
           $scope.columnToSortBy = null;
           $scope.rows = results["rows"];
           $scope.reverse = false;
           $scope.orderByAsc = false;
           $scope.orderByDesc = false;
           $scope.orderByNothing = true;
      // })
 }
})
```

---

***UPDATED QUESTION TO REFLECT CHANGES BASED ON @Gaurav ADVICE.***

Comment: use web worker. and run it in background

Comment: why do you need 1000 row ? use pagination, the user can't handle that number of rows. That would be compile less information and DOM won't be freezed

Comment: also, better to use a directive and don't handle dom from your controller.. let the controller just request data using $http and create results rows, and let your template to generate the html by itself

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal Hey. What is a good webworker for angular? It doesn't actually seem like the issue is having an issue until ng-repeat. The code in the controller is fine and dandy. It is when it is time for ng-repeat to do its work that the dom freezes....

Comment: @Gonzalo How would I create a directive for this? I am a total noob.

Comment: You can use https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat

Comment: It is very fast already on my chrome - https://jsfiddle.net/S_YOU/6p5bfnr6/2/ - may be your angular version and browser is not the best.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do its in angularjs way Eg: your html should be like this

```
<table class='results'>
  <tr class='results-column-tr'>
    <th ng-repeat="column in columns"><h6 class='results-column-titles' ng-click='sortBy(column.name)">{{column.name}}</h6><img ng-show='orderByDesc' src='/static/images/asc.gif'><img ng-show='orderByAsc' src='/static/images/desc.gif'><img ng-show='orderByNothing' src='/static/images/bg.gif'>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat='row in rows | orderBy:columnToSortBy:reverse'>
    <td ng-repeat="column in columns" class='results-data' ng-bind='row[column.name]'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and controller

```
mainQueryModule.controller("newQueryController", function($scope, $http){
  var results = {columns:[{"type": "STRING", "name": "nk"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Bn"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Sk"},{"type": "STRING", "name": "ank"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Bnk"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Skk"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Name"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Phone"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Age"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Tank"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Bank"}, {"type": "STRING", "name": "Skunk"}], rows:[]};
  for(index = 0; index < 1000; index++){
    results['rows'].push({nk: "select * fotm ;ldfg;lkjdopiusergknds;lkbjs;dlfkjoisdug;lkjsdfg;lkjsdfgl;kjsdfg;lkjsdfgl;iusoe[rtuoipejl;ksdjsdjgoupsdgoupieopiutwjsgoji;duiejlds;fgjsdjgdfgsjsdgsdfgjsdgkl", Bn: 35, Sk: 567, ank: "ank", Bnk: "Bnk", Skk: "Skk", Name: "Erik", Phone: 100000+index, Age: 29+index, Bank: "Big"+index, Tank: 16+index, Skunk: "123"+index})
  }
  $scope.columns = results["columns"];
  $scope.rows = results["rows"];
});
```

Don't do this in jquery style.

Comment: I agree. I should be doing it the angular js way. Here is my issue. If I do it this way I need it to be dynamic so when $scope.columns and $scope.rows change, I can still use orderBy. Will this work for that?

Comment: Surly its work for dynamic content and orderBy will be persist all the time.

Comment: Hey. So I implemented your solution. It is dynamic. orderBy does indeed work. But the dom still freezes with larger datasets. Any way to make this faster? Would putting ng-repeat in a directive make it faster?

Comment: you need paging or infinity scroll for this, because ngRepeat is very slow for large data, you can handle large amount of data using ngReapeat with any third party library.

Comment: Will I still be able to display 10000 rows on the page with infinity sort? If so, will I also be able to filter with something like _Lodash or even orderBy?